# Creating a clone name for a directory in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

is there a way to have an alias name in cmd (command prompt) for a directory.
For example I am working with this directory in cmd:

```
C:\Users\joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\example>
```

but I like it to show as `c:\projects>` or `project>` cause I dont want the directory to take up a whole line in the cmd screen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Windows Vista or 7, you can do this by create a Directory Symbolic Link.

`C:\>mklink /D projects "C:\Users\joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\example"`

`C:\>cd projects`

you may need administrator privilege.

Comment: for XP you can follow these steps :http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: Thank you so much, I just want to add that you need to run the cmd as administrator.